# How can we detect inconsistency in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe for which I want to detect if the results are inconsistent:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3, 1], [4, 5, 6, 0], [7, 8, 9, 0], [4, 5, 6, 1], [1, 2, 3, 1]]),
...                    columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'result'])
>>> df
   a  b  c  result
0  1  2  3       1
1  4  5  6       0
2  7  8  9       0
3  4  5  6       1
4  1  2  3       1
```

My goal is to drop those rows that show different results for the same values (id 1 and 3 should be dropped). 
I know I can detect duplicates and loop over the results

```
>>> df[df.duplicated(['a', 'b', 'c'], keep=False)]
   a  b  c  result
0  1  2  3       1
1  4  5  6       0
3  4  5  6       1
4  1  2  3       1
```

But I was wondering if there's a more pythonic way of getting (and dropping) those indexes.

Answer (score 4):

I would compute the number of unique values per unique set of a, b, c values:

```
to_keep = df[df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'])['result'].transform('nunique') == 1]
```

it gives:

```
   a  b  c  result
0  1  2  3       1
2  7  8  9       0
4  1  2  3       1
```

Comment: Great suggestion, I like your flip-thinking :)

Comment: I've tested this on a dataframe with 50.000 rows and 50 columns, and it takes forever to compute. My own answer below has a result in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use a bitwise operator

```
>>> duplicates = df[df.duplicated(['a', 'b', 'c'], keep=False) & ~df.duplicated(['a', 'b', 'c', 'result'], keep=False)]
>>> duplicates
   a  b  c  result
1  4  5  6       0
3  4  5  6       1
>>> df.drop(duplicates.index)
>>> df
   a  b  c  result
0  1  2  3       1
2  7  8  9       0
4  1  2  3       1
```

Not sure if this is a clear solution for dataframes with a lot of columns

Comment: ur output is different from Serge's, and different from ur expected output. IIUC, u want to get rid of entries that change in the result column

Comment: I've added how I would drop duplicate values

Comment: I suggest not drop index values by mask, because it working only for unique index values, if some duplicates in remove also rows which not need.

Answer (score 0):

Group and then discard results which have more than one values for result

```py
a = df.groupby(['a','b','c'])['result'].apply(set).reset_index()
a_filter = a[a.result.apply(len)==1].copy()
a_filter.result = a.result.apply(lambda x:next(iter(x)))
a_filter
```

Gives output:

```
    a   b   c   result
0   1   2   3   1
2   7   8   9   0
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not drop index values by mask, because it working only for unique index values, if some duplicates in remove also rows which not need.

Better is filtering by inverted mask by `~`:

```
cols = ['a','b','c']
mask1 = df.duplicated(cols, keep=False) 
mask2 = ~df.duplicated(cols + ['result'], keep=False)

df = df[~(mask1 & mask2)]
print (df)
   a  b  c  result
0  1  2  3       1
2  7  8  9       0
4  1  2  3       1
```

Or use `|` for bitwise `OR` with swap `~` from `mask2` to `mask1`:

```
cols = ['a','b','c']
mask1 = ~df.duplicated(cols, keep=False) 
mask2 = df.duplicated(cols + ['result'], keep=False)

df = df[(mask1 | mask2)]
print (df)
   a  b  c  result
0  1  2  3       1
2  7  8  9       0
4  1  2  3       1
```